# What happens with constraints when a view is begin to be hidden?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

Question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617991/what-happens-with-constraints-when-a-view-is-removed) but I am interesting in what happen when UIView change `isHidden` value.

For Example:

    `|       |       |
-[ViewA]-[ViewB]-[ViewC]-
    |       |       |`

at draft:

`[X]` -> views

`|` and `-` -> constraints

What is happen when: `ViewB.isHidden = true` How to correct handle showing/hiding subviews (without `UIStackView`) in code? Should I manually set constraints to active/inactive?

Comment: Nothing happens. If you close your eyes, your Mac is still there? Same thing. (I hope no one steals it in the meantime, for then I'll be proven wrong...) :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, hiding a view (by setting `isHidden`) has no effect on layout. Hidden views participate in layout. Any constraints connected to the view are still enforced. The area occupied by the now-hidden view is still reserved for it.

This is useful because it allows you to use hidden views as “spacers” to create layouts (in Interface Builder) that you cannot otherwise create. (In code, you can use `UILayoutGuide`s instead of hidden views, but IB doesn't support creating layout guides.)

`UIStackView` is different from other views. `UIStackView` observes the `isHidden` property of each of its arranged subviews. When an arranged subview's `isHidden` changes, the `UIStackView` updates constraints to make or remove the area used by that subview.

No other view does what `UIStackView` does, so no other view adjusts the layout of its subviews when they become hidden or visible.

Comment: so, if I understand correct, if I want to hide subview in code I need to inactive every connected constraint to it if I want to relayout view?

Comment: If you want to hide a subview, you set its `isHidden` property to `true`. If you also want to rearrange the remaining views to fill the space previously occupied by the now-hidden subview, then you need to update your constraints accordingly. It will usually be more complicated than just deactivating the constraints connected to the now-hidden view.

Comment: if other view are connected properly depending on the width constraint you want to deactivated they will resize accordingly

Comment: I agree. I just want to be sure that any hiding/showing view requires manually inactive/active constraints. Forget about rearrange context. :) I want to understand differences between `UIStackView` and classic `subviews`

Comment: This is really surprising since the behaviour is not consistent, I wonder how to maintain the constraints even when view is hidden inside `UIStackView`.

Comment: @CyberMew It would be better to post a top-level question rather than ask that in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @robmayoff, good idea, though I just did a search and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494061/how-to-preserve-constraints-for-hidden-views-within-uistackview, so I guess I won't be creating another question for now